# App layout not rendering correctly on first run

Tags: reactjs, react-native

The app i have built contains header, content body and a footer. And it is locked in landscape orientation and the method is stated in componentDidMount(). However on the first launch on my own physical device, the layout is appearing to be incorrect and missing elements such as the whole footer and the buttons. The sizes of components is not rendering correctly either. I need to Hot reload once to get the correct layout every time. Further reloading will not affect the correctly rendered layout.

May i know what is the cause of the problem?

Comment: Are you using any sort of navigation library? Are you using state or props for dynamic changes in the app? Some code here or a minimal working example would help a lot.

Comment: Yes, i did imported react-native-orientation to lock the landscape mode of app. I did not declare any state yet.

Comment: There's not much to go on here but perhaps the components on the screen are rendered first and then your orientation lock kicks in to make it landscape?

Comment: Hi, i just realize the problems should be with the package i imported or something wrong with the lifecycle (i declared componentWillMount() only). Now i found another way to deal with orientation without using the package. The problem of rendering is no longer exist

Comment: Glad to know that! :)